# Maven test scope dependency change does not recompile module's tests

Tags: maven, teamcity

We have a maven multi-module project in which the following weirdness occurred:

- **module-x** has a TEST (src/test/java/...) which depends on code provided by **module-y**, whose code is not otherwise used in module-x (i.e. nothing in src/main/java/... depends on module-y)
- **module-x** therefore defines a dependency on module-y, but with `<scope>test</scope>` and uses that code in one of its tests
- someone changed a constructor in **module-y** and committed the code that broke the **module-x** test (as it was using the old constructor parameters)
- TeamCity ran `java org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f app-parent/pom.xml -B integration-test` when it saw the commit
- the build succeeded because maven did NOT recompile/rerun **module-x** TEST code, it just recompiled **module-y** and everything that depends on it with default *compile* scope

I'm sure people will point out, why is that test even in module-x, etc, but this weird setup aside for a minute. What I want to understand is this:

If some project (module-x) has a test dependency (module-y) that changes and is recompiled, should not maven then notice this and do a fresh "test-compile" for the project (module-x) that "test-depends" on what changed (module-y)? Is what I saw here normal behavior?

EDIT: from comment replies it seems like the fact that TeamCity is being used may be a factor; I clarified the command used in the sequence list above.

EDIT 2: I should note that the parameter "-f app-parent/pom.xml" is actually the main module that basically depends on "the world" and is where one would run from command-line "mvn test" or "mvn clean package" to rebuild everything.

Comment: How are you editing and running your maven codes?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean by "maven codes".

Comment: Are you running the builds through eclipse or are you running them through command line?

Comment: This is run through command line. The TeamCity server is polling SVN for changes and as soon as it sees a new commit, the working copy on the server is updated and then maven is invoked from command line. The exact command is: "mvn -f main-module/pom.xml integration-test --threads=8"

Comment: Apologies, edited my comment reply. Apparently teamcity launches the main plexus launcher instead of using the mvn script. So the command is the following: "java org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f app-parent/pom.xml -B integration-test --threads 8"

Comment: Is this project a multi module build? If yes than using `mvn -f Module/pom.xml` is the wrong way. Better us `mvn -pl module clean packag` or `mvn -pl module verify` ...

Comment: What is wrong with the '-f' parameter? It's the main POM that depends on all modules of the project. Also, I don't want to clean and rebuild everything as it takes a while...